# Excel - SUMIF and Weekday

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Note: I am putting this question as Excel and Google Docs as they have a ton of overlap for simple questions like this.

I have two columns of data. A date of a purchase and how much that purchase was for.

```
    A               B
11/23/2015      $59
12/5/2015       $23.32
1/21/2016       $12.09
1/22/2016       $78.21
1/22/2016       $5.88
2/14/2016       $0.13
...             ...
(thousands of rows below this)
```

I want to SUM the amount of money spent on Mondays, Tuesdays, Wednesdays, etc.

If I use `SUMIF`, I run into this problem:

```
=SUMIF(A:A, WEEKDAY(A:A), B:B)
                ^ WEEKDAY only takes in a single date value.
```

I **do not** want a function that I have to drag downwards.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [query](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) function:

```
=QUERY({A:B},"select dayOfWeek(Col1), sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by dayOfWeek(Col1)")
```

[image]

In this formula I used Array `{A:B}` and notation `Col1, Col2...` in the formula because now when you add new columns, the formula won't fail.

---

And the similiar formula, using `sumif`:

```
 ={arrayformula(unique(weekday(A:A))),arrayformula(sumif(week‌​day(A:A),unique(week‌​day(A:A)),B:B))}
```

Comment: This is interesting as I've used `QUERY` before. Does this imply that `SUMIF` just won't work at all in this case?

Comment: I think, sumif is possible, but it will be harder to make the formula work: you need to predefine weekdays, something like: =`{arrayformula(unique(weekday(A:A))),arrayformula(sumif(weekday(A:A),unique(weekday(A:A)),B:B))}`

Answer (score 0):

In Excel you do it with this Array formula. Array formula needs to be entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

```
{=SUM(IF(WEEKDAY($A$2:$A$1000,1)=E2,$B$2:$B$1000,0))}
```

This assumes your day of week in number is E2. The second parameter in Weekday function defines how you number the days of Week. Here I have used 1 which means 1 = Sunday and 7 = Saturday

Comment: Or you could use this, if you don't want to use an arrayformula:                    =SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY($A$2:$A$1000,1)=E2),$B$2:$B$1000)

Comment: So putting `{` `}` around your formula turns it into an array formula? How does that work? What functionality does that grant it?

Comment: No, Excel will do that automatically when you press Ctrl-Shift-Enter after type the formula. If you already pressed enter, hit F2 and press Ctrl-Shift-Enter.